# c# windows forms ERROR "Exepcion no controlada(the conection is already open)" en el conector con mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2019

pasa que estoy haciendo un proyecto de windows form y me da el siguiente error en el conector con mysql, se agradece su ayuda
Nota:Me funciona bien el el visual 2015, pero en el visual 2019 no me funciona 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class conector
{
    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Uid=root;password=;database=restaurante;port=3306");
    public MySqlConnection obtenerConexcion()
    {

        try
        {
            conexion.Open();//abre la conexión con la bd
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return conexion;

    }
}[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Abres la conexion pero en ningun lado la cierras , seguramente te funciona la primera vez que ocupas el codigo pero a la siguiente te manda error

```
    class conector
```

{
    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;Uid=root;password=;database=restaurante;port=3306");
    public MySqlConnection obtenerConexcion()
    {

```
    try
    {
        conexion.Open();//abre la conexión con la bd
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    return conexion;
conexion.Close();

}
```

}

Con la linea de conexion.close(); deberia de arreglarse